# Ctrl-M Filewatcher job invoking a shell script fails

Tags: java

Facing the below error when running the filewatcher job. File that is being watched is already in place.

> - ctmfw /amex/RSM_1099CTEST.txt CREATE 0 1800 10 3 0 N 0001 2359 NO_MIN_AGE NO_MAX_AGE
>     /opt/bmc/controlm/cmagentd/ctm/runtime/CMD.0000ctkt_002: line 2:
>     ctmfw: command not found

Can someone help me identify the cause of this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Installing `ctmfw` (or putting it on the `PATH`) could help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Deepak!What is ctmfw?..CTRL-M team informed us that all the agents required to run the job are installed.How to put it on path?

Comment: Oh..ctmfw- filewatcher job is already installed.Can you please let me know how to add it to PATH?

Answer (score 0):

The **ctmfw** command is provided by Control-M/Agent component. You must validate that you are running that Job on a server where a Control-M Agent is installed. In addition, it must be executed with the **operating system user** under which the agent was installed or, with a user who has execution privileges over the ctmfw utility.